# How to convert existing text data in hdfs to Avro?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, avro, avro-tools

I have a table in hdfs which is stored in Text format, so now i have a requirement to add new column in between. So I thought to load new columns in avro as Avro supports schema evolution,but now the previous data is still in text format.

Comment: ORC and Parquet also support column additions... Alternatively, Text format allows columns to be added at the end. And this really isn't a problem because you can just change the field order of the select query

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have a table you can load that directly into avro table from hive, if not you can create hive table for that text file and load that to avro table.
Something like

> ```
> create table test(fields type)  row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textile location 'textfilepath';
> create table avrotbl like test stored as avrofile;
> insert into abrotbl select * from test;
> ```

Comment: Will this generate the avro schema correctly? I know it'll work for ORC or Parquet because those are columnar formats